# Linear Gradient on Input Slider not works correctly in IE 11/edge

Tags: css

I have the following code to style my rang slider in IE :

```
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
width: 100%;
cursor: pointer;
background: transparent;
border-color: transparent;
border: 20px solid;
border-radius: 50px !important;
color: transparent;
transition: border 1000ms ease;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 0%, #43e018 100%);
border: 2px solid #000101;
border-radius: 1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 0%, #43e018 100%);
border: 2px solid #000101;
border-radius: 1px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
border: 4px solid;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 28px;
width: 28px;
max-width: 80px;
position: relative;
bottom: 12px;
background-color: #000000;
cursor: -webkit-grab;
transition: border 1000ms ease;
}
```

This gives me the following result:

> [image: Result]

As you can see, the linear gradient dosent seem work correctly. 
So what i want is, that the linear gradient goes from red to green in one flow.

Comment: your result not displaying can you please add again

Comment: Does it works now ?

Comment: yes  its showing now

Comment: So - can u tell me why i get this style and how i can handle it ?